# asking about orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

1) How to proof this as orthogonal matrix U preserve angles:
$$<Ux,Uy> = <x,y>$$
for any x and y.

2) How to prove that eigenvalue have unit absolute value?

Comment: Well, what do you know about orthogonal matrices? What do you know about inner products? about eigenvalues?

Comment: as far as i understand orthogonal matrix is the transpose matrix is equal to inverse matrix. about inner product and eigenvalues not quit understand. Can help?

Comment: use $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R^{n}},A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}:\left<x,Ay\right>=\left<A^{t}x,y\right>$

Comment: You can help yourself by learning what an eigenvalue is, and by learning something about inner products. What's helpful here is that $\langle u,v\rangle=u^tv$, where I write $u^t$ for the transpose of $u$.

Answer (score 1):

Using properties of adjoints: $\langle x, y \rangle = \langle x, (U^* U)y \rangle = \langle Ux, Uy \rangle$.

By setting $x=y$ we get $\|Ux\| = \|x\|$.

If $v$ is a unit  eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have
$1 = \|v\| = \|Uv\| = |\lambda| \|v\| = |\lambda|$.

Answer (score 0):

The first question has virtually been answered by Max. Concerning the second one. Suppose
\begin{equation}
 Ux = \lambda x \hspace{5mm}\Rightarrow\hspace{5mm} x'U' = \lambda x'
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
 ||x||^2 = x'x = x'U'Ux = ||Ux||^2 = ||\lambda x||^2 = |\lambda|^2||x||^2 \hspace{5mm}\Rightarrow\hspace{5mm} |\lambda| = 1
\end{equation}

Comment: You need to be a little careful, if $U=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $U$ is orthogonal, but the eigenvalues are $\pm i$, not $\pm 1$.

Comment: You are completely right. I have adapted the proof.